# Add custom data- attribute to Option component react-select

Tags: reactjs, testing, components, react-select

I am creating a test for my dropdown searchable component using [react-select](https://react-select.com/) library.
I am not able to add `data-testid` attribute to the `Option` component when customizing that component as it is defined in [react-select documentation](https://react-select.com/components#replacing-components).

The `data-testid` attribute does not show in the DOM for `Option` element.

**Option component**

```js
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';

const CustomOption = (props: OptionProps<SearchDropdownOption, false>) => (
  <components.Option {...props} data-testid="test-id" />
);
```

For example i had a **success** with the `Input` component for search version of the dropdown and `data-testid` attribute shows in the DOM:

**Input component**

```js
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';

const CustomInput = (props: InputProps<SearchDropdownOption, false>) => (
  <components.Input {...props} data-testid="test-id" />
);
```

And than using it in `Select` component:

```js
<Select<SearchDropdownOption, false>
  components={{
    Input: CustomInput,
    Option: CustomOption,
  }}
  isSearchable={isSearchable}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to add custom attribute `data-testid` directly to the `Option` component as i did for `Input` component. I need to extend this component with an HTML `span` element, or any other, and add this attribute to that element directly:

```js
const CustomOption = (props: OptionProps<SearchDropdownOption, false>) => {
  return (
    <components.Option {...props}>
      <span data-testid="test-id" key={props.innerProps.key}>
        {props.data.label}
      </span>
    </components.Option>
  );
};
```

**NOTE**
This `key` prop is important as it gives the regular React uniqueness to the element and value for that can be used from the react-select's `innerProps` property:

```js
key={props.innerProps.key}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const OptionWrapper = (customProps: IOptionProps) =>
  (nativeProps: OptionProps) => (
    <components.Option
      {...nativeProps}
      innerProps={{
        ...nativeProps.innerProps,
        ...customProps
      }}
    />
  );

Option = OptionWrapper({ 'data-testid':"test-id" })
```

Try this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Dimitrii for your answer. But this wont work as `Option` component does not take props like this. Some of the components do, but this one does not. That is why i needed to add span inside.